# Detecting scroll direction in a nested ListView influtter

Tags: flutter

I have a listview. The children of this ListView are horizontal pageviews.How can I detect the scroll direction of the listview (up and down) . Note that the scroll of the horizontal pageviews should not be detected.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your listview a separate `ScrollController()` and get the current position using it.

For example, you can also check the direction like below:

```
NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (notification) {
    final ScrollDirection direction = notification.direction;
    print('direction: $direction');
    return true;
  },
  child: VerticalMainListView()
)
```

[`ScrollDirection`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/ScrollDirection.html) enum has two properties, `reverse` and `forward` through which you can check if it was scrolled up / down.

Comment: I Just want to detect scroll direction (up or down). How can I do so with ScrollController()

Comment: Updated the answer with an example @KevinMwangi

Comment: Using notificationListener listens to both the pageview scrolling and the listview scrolling. I wanted only a listener on the listview only